# Windows Powershell - Simplest way to run a bunch of commands and save output

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, mongo-shell

In Windows Powershell, I want to make a script that runs a bunch of commands in succession.

Like so:

```
mongo a.js > aout.txt
mongo b.js > bout.txt
...
```

I'm using PowerShell to get access to the linux like `>` command.
But I can't figure out how to easily write this script. I assume it's trivial.
I tried writing a batch script but that doesn't work, due to `>` isn't supported.

How would you do it?

Comment: `1..1000 | % {mongo "$_.js" | Out-File -Path "C:\data\$_.txt"}` Not Tested. Do you have a file naming scheme? I thought for sure '>','>>','2>','2>>',... were supported in bat files. I even have bat scripts that use them. Check the Mongo exe to see if it supports file output.

Comment: Redirection (>) most definitely is supported in batch files.

Comment: Odd I did `START /WAIT mongo a.js > a.txt` newline `START /WAIT mongo b.js > b.txt` which didn't work :( and yes mongo support output, it works when I do it manually

Comment: lose the start /wait. Executables don't need start and command line executables already block until the exe is finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file with a `.ps1` extension.  Put this in the file:

```
param($path = $pwd)
mongo $path\a.js > $path\aout.txt
mongo $path\b.js > $path\bout.txt
```

The above assumes mongo is in your path.  Now make sure you have execution policy set to allow scripts to run.  Execute this in PowerShell (running as admin):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned # you can also use Unrestricted if you'd like
```

Then execute your script e.g.:

```
C:\> C:\mymongo\mongo-it.ps1 C:\mymongo
```